# Do i have to cut my vanity for my sink trap?

Tags: plumbing

I happened to get a new vanity cabinet for a slight bathroom refresh and upon installing it I noticed that the vanity shelf is in the way of the trap.

Is there a way to buy a different p trap so I don't have to cut the vanity shelf, Or is it the best option at this point?

Do I have to cut this vanity cabinet shelf?

[image]

Comment: Are _[sic]_ the problem that the trap needs to extend through the bottom of the vanity or that the drain from the sink hits the elbow that comes out of the wall? It's difficult to tell from the images provided.

Comment: I think the trap will need to be extended through The shelf and the pop up drain pipe is hitting it as well. I'm thinking of removing the white pvc that's going to the street drain to give a bit more clearance to alleviate the pop up drain pipe placement but it appears I'll still have to cut the cabinet shelf to accommodate the p trap.

Comment: Adding a 45° bend at the wall to swing the drain line off to the side would give you space between the tailpiece dropping from the sink and the PVC drain. It doesn't help with the altitude issue. A [bottle trap](https://www.google.com/search?q=bottle+trap) might help, but I don't know if they are code compliant at your vanity's address.

Comment: Hmmm that may work, I'll do some research into my city's code to confirm. Thanks.

Comment: Aside: Some informative reading on various traps vs. code compliance is [here](http://forms.iapmo.org/email_marketing/codespotlight/2017/Oct12.htm), including the failure modes.

Answer (score 2):

If your shelf is not removable, *that  appears to be the case*, then you will need  to cut a space out in the shelf wide enough to accommodate the plumbing.

A  Jig-saw will be the best tool for the job.

> Is there a way to buy a different p trap so I don't have to cut the
> vanity shelf, Or is it the best option at this point?

No, the P-trap is a standard size, The only other option is to cut open the wall and reconfigure the pipe in the wall,  move the sanitary  tee up.(*but you have limited space to move it up because of the height of the sink tail piece*.)

**I believe that cutting the vanity is the best option.**

Comment: Before you cut anything, ascertain whether an assembled p-trap would be able to completely fit in height-wise, with or without the suggested 45-degree elbow. It may mean, as another poster said, that the drain outlet will have to be moved up and you will regret it if you first cut a hole in the shelf!